# Tuning the mysql server in linux

Tags: mysql, database, linux

I have a mysql server in linux platform. I need to do performance tuning in that mysql server which is innodb engine.I want know the manual configuration in my.cnf file. so, what are all the important innodb parameters to be configure ? Because innodb and myisam engines are having different tuning operations. please tell some useful things to do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [MySQL Tuner](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl)
This is good starting point for `MySQL` performance tuning.

You should also be running some kind of monitoring software that is able to graph
you `MySQL` health. This is vastly helpful when the performance trouble comes in.
I would recommend you `munin` with the `MySQL` [plugins](http://munin-monitoring.org/).

Regards -- Luke

Comment: MySQL Tuner gives you the configuration you need to apply in your my.cnf file.